# django-paypal unable to handle notification signal

Tags: python, django, paypal, django-paypal

I'm using django standard ipn and unable to handle notification signal. 
Payment goes very smoothly only notification part doesn't work.
this is my signals.py

```
def show_me_the_money(sender, **kwargs):
    ipn_obj = sender
    if ipn_obj.payment_status == ST_PP_COMPLETED:
        print("yey")
        order = Orders.objects.get(id=38)
        order.paid = True
        order.save()

valid_ipn_received.connect(show_me_the_money)
```

apps.py

```
class PaymentConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'payment'
    verbose_name = 'Payment'


    def ready(self):
        import payment.signals
```

**init**.py

```
default_app_config = 'payment.apps.PaymentConfig'
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^payment/', include('payment.urls', namespace='payment')),
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings/base.py or settings.py and insert into ALLOWED_HOSTS your DNS, or if you don't have any problem you could use just ALLOWED_HOSTS='*'